# Replacing one data frame value from another based on timestamp Criterion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to Python and may be it's a very basic question for many here so apologies in advance and please bear with me.
I have a timeseries of water level records where the timestamps are not continuous. I want to create a new timeseries which is continuous and for the intervals where there is no data I want to assign nan. I created a continuous time series with Nan values for level. I am trying to fill the observed values in it using df.replace function in a iterative way but I cannot produce what I want. Here is the same of my code:

```
Input data example:
Time stamp                 Level
2020-06-18 18:00:00        161.287
2020-06-18 21:00:00        161.286
2020-06-19 12:00:00        161.283
2020-06-19 15:00:00        161.283
```

```
dti = dti = pd.date_range("2020-05-01", periods=1224, freq="3H")
dti_df = pd.DataFrame(dti, columns=['Timestamp'])
dti_df["Level"] = np.nan
dti_df
df3 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\krusm\Documents\water Levels Resampled.csv')
for i in dti_df.index:
    for j in df3.index:
        if dti_df['Timestamp'][i] == df3['Timestamp'][j]:
            dti_df['Level'][i].replace(df3['Level'][j], inplace = True)
          
        else:
            pass
dti_df
```

This code runs without any error however produces the Nan timeseries.
NaN data frame created through first part of the code:

```
Time stamp                 Level
2020-06-18 18:00:00        NaN
2020-06-18 21:00:00        NaN
2020-06-19 00:00:00        NaN
2020-06-18 03:00:00        NaN
2020-06-19 06:00:00        NaN
2020-06-19 09:00:00        NaN
2020-06-19 12:00:00        NaN
2020-06-19 15:00:00        NaN
```

```
Output Expectation:
Time stamp                 Level
2020-06-18 18:00:00        161.287
2020-06-18 21:00:00        161.286
2020-06-19 00:00:00        NaN
2020-06-18 03:00:00        NaN
2020-06-19 06:00:00        NaN
2020-06-19 09:00:00        NaN
2020-06-19 12:00:00        161.283
2020-06-19 15:00:00        161.283
```

Comment: It would help to see a sample of the input data and expected output, see [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] to include a [mcve]

Comment: I updated the question with a sample. Hope you can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that your input df, `df3`, has had the column renamed to `Timestamp` and the dtype converted to datetime. In this case, you can just use `merge` to make your life much easier

```
dti = pd.date_range("2020-05-01", periods=1224, freq="3H")
dti_df = pd.DataFrame(dti, columns=['Timestamp'])
new_df=pd.merge(left=dti_df,right=df3, on='Timestamp',how='left')

new_df.iloc[390:400,:]

    Timestamp           Level
390 2020-06-18 18:00:00 161.287
391 2020-06-18 21:00:00 161.286
392 2020-06-19 00:00:00 NaN
393 2020-06-19 03:00:00 NaN
394 2020-06-19 06:00:00 NaN
395 2020-06-19 09:00:00 NaN
396 2020-06-19 12:00:00 161.283
397 2020-06-19 15:00:00 161.283
398 2020-06-19 18:00:00 NaN
399 2020-06-19 21:00:00 NaN
```